# Mostrar datos de una BD en una modal laravel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sql-server, laravel-5

espero alguien me pueda ayudar a resolver esto, estoy utilizando Laravel y SQL, quiero mostrar datos en una Modal, los datos deben de ser extraídos desde mi BD, esta es mi tabla donde tengo los dos botones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón de la modal es el segundo el de color azul el cual lo tengo en el siguiente método donde muestro los datos de la tabla:

```
public function busquedaAgendada(Request $request){

        $programa = self::$programa;
        $ejercicio = self::$ejercicio;

        $columns = array(
            0 => 'fecha',
            1 => 'numeroSesion',
            2 => 'Tipo',
            3 => 'Casos',
            4 => 'montoPropuesto',
            5 => 'm.idSesion'
        );

        $limit = $request->input('length');
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

        $totalData = DB::table('tblSesionesComite as sc')
                        ->join('tblCComites as c','c.idComite','sc.idComite')
                        ->where('c.idProgramaSocial',$programa)
                        ->count();

        $totalFiltered = $totalData;

        if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){

            $sesiones = DB::table('tblSesionesComite as sc')
                        ->select(
                            'sc.idSesion','sc.numeroSesion','sc.montoPropuesto','sc.Estatus','sc.Casos',
                            'sc.montoAprobado','sc.idSedeSesion',
                            DB::raw("
                                (CASE
                                    WHEN sc.Tipo = 0 THEN 'ORDINARIA'
                                    ELSE 'EXTRAORDINARIA'
                                END) AS tipoSesion
                            "),
                            DB::raw("(CONCAT(DAY(sc.fecha),'/',MONTH(sc.fecha),'/',YEAR(sc.fecha))) AS Fecha"),
                            DB::raw("
                                (CASE
                                    WHEN sc.Estatus = 0 THEN 'PENDIENTE'
                                    ELSE 'SESIONADA'
                                END) AS estatusSesion
                            "),'c.idProgramaSocial'
                        )
                        ->join('tblCComites as c','c.idComite','sc.idComite')
                        ->where('sc.Ejercicio',$ejercicio)
                        ->where('c.idProgramaSocial',$programa)
                        ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                        ->offset($start)
                        ->limit($limit)
                        ->get();

        }else{

        }

        $data = array();

        if(!empty($sesiones))
        {
            foreach ($sesiones as $sesion)
            {
                $nestedData['idSesion'] = $sesion->idSesion;
                $nestedData['fecha'] = $sesion->Fecha;
                $nestedData['numeroSesion'] = $sesion->numeroSesion;
                $nestedData['Tipo'] = $sesion->tipoSesion;
                $nestedData['Casos'] = $sesion->Casos;
                $nestedData['montoPropuesto'] = number_format($sesion->montoPropuesto,2);
                // $nestedData['costoSesionComite'] = number_format($sesion->costoSesionComite,2);

                if($sesion->Estatus == 0){
                    $nestedData['editar'] =
                            '<td>
                                <center>
                                    <button onclick=\'editar("'.$sesion->idSesion.'");\' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar sesión" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
                                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button data-title-modal="Enviar convocatoria" data-action-modal="show" data-icon-modal="fas fa-file-import" data-id-modal="'.$sesion->idSesion.'"
                                            data-vista-modal="sesion.agendadas.modal.show" data-width-modal="80%" data-pt-title="Enviar convocatoria"
                                            title="Enviar convocatoria" class="myModal btn btn-outline-info">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </center>
                            </td>';
                }else{
                    $nestedData['editar'] =
                            '<td>
                                <center>
                                    <i class="estatus-canalizado fas fa-check-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="La sesión de comité ha finalizado, no se puede hacer ningun cambio."></i>
                                </center>
                            </td>';
                }

                $data[] = $nestedData;
            }
        }

        $json_data = array(
                    "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),
                    "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),
                    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
                    "data"            => $data
                    );

        $jsonp = preg_match('/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i', $_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : false;

        echo $jsonp.'('.json_encode($json_data).');';
    }
```

AL oprimir ese botón **"Enviar convocatoria"** se abre la modal, este es el código de mi modal:

```
<!-- Modal Sesíones -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="padding-right: 5%; padding-left: 5%;"><br>
                    <div><br><br>
                        <p><b>
                            <strong>LIC.</strong> <strong>ANA</strong> <br>
                            <strong>DIRECTORA GENERAL<br>
                            <strong>PRESENTE.</strong><br>
                        </b></p>
                    </div><br><br>
                    <div style="text-align: justify;line-height: 28px;">
                        <div style="font-size: 1em;">
                            RECIBA UN CORDIAL SALUDO; POR ESTE CONDUCTO ME PERMITO INVITAR A USTED A LA <strong>{{ $numeroSesion }}ª. </strong> SESIÓN <strong>{{ $tipo }}</strong>
                            DE COMITÉ DEL PROGRAMA. PARA EL EJERCICIO FISCAL 2020; MISMA QUE SE LLEVARÁ A CABO DE FORMA VIRTUAL.
                        </div><br>
                        <div>
                            SIN OTRO PARTICULAR POR EL MOMENTO Y ESPERANDO CONTAR DE FORMA VIRTUAL CON SU VALIOSA PRESENCIA, QUEDO DE USTED.
                        </div><br><br>
                        <hr style="border-color:#cacaca;">
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <p><b>DIRECCIÓN GENERAL DE GESTORÍA Y VINCULACIÓN INTERINSTITUCIONAL</b><br>
                            <b>SUBSECRETARÍA DE ADMINISTRACIÓN E INVERSIÓN</b><br>
                        </div><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div align="right">
                        <button onclick="enviarCorreo();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enviar convocatoria a los participantes del comité" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-invoice" aria-hidden="true"></i> ENVIAR CONVOCATORIA
                        </button>
                    </div><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!!Html::script('js/sesion/agendadas/modal/show.js')!!} 
{{-- </div> --}}
```

Al querer abrir la modal me marca este error, que no están definidas las variables:

```
{
    "message": "Undefined variable: numeroSesion (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Acciones\\resources\\views\\sesion\\agendadas\\modal\\show.blade.php)",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Acciones\\storage\\framework\\views\\c14b2d7a205c1eb103ba1e0f51d1c35127e07b04.php",
    "line": 16,
    "trace": [
```

Pero la no se como pasar las variables por método ajax, este es el Js de la modal donde lo intentaba poner:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    cargarComponentes();

});

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $('#overlay').show();
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { 
        $('#overlay').hide();
    }
});

function cargarComponentes() {

    $.post(fullPathName + '/sesion/agendadas/modal/', {
        _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
    }, function(item, status) {

        $('#lblUsuario').text(item.UserName + ' (' + $.trim(item.Nombre) + ')');


    });

}
```

Esta es la consulta de la BD donde quiero mostrar los datos en la modal:

```
public function modal(Request $request){

        select sc.idSesion, sc.numeroSesion, sc.montoPropuesto, sc.Estatus, sc.Casos, sc.montoAprobado, sc.idSedeSesion,
       CASE WHEN sc.Tipo = 0 THEN 'ORDINARIA' ELSE 'EXTRAORDINARIA' END AS tipoSesion,
       CONCAT(DAY(sc.fecha),'/',MONTH(sc.fecha),'/',YEAR(sc.fecha)) AS Fecha,
       CASE WHEN sc.Estatus = 0 THEN 'PENDIENTE' ELSE 'SESIONADA' END AS estatusSesion, c.idProgramaSocial

       FROM tblSesionesComite as sc
       JOIN tblCComites as c ON c.idComite = sc.idComite

    }
```

Esta es la Ruta de la modal:

```
Route::post('/sesion/agendadas/modal/','Sesion\SesionController@modal');
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no se como resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente estas queriendo obtener el valor de **`{{ $numeroSesion }}`** en tu vista, pero este se esta asignado a un array ($nestedData), como un indice. Deberias acceder asi

```
$nestedData['numeroSesion ']
```

Comment: @Ezequien Pero ese método lo utilizo para mostrar datos en la tabla donde esta el botón antes de abrir el modal, lo que no se es como mostrar ese dato en la vista.